# How to split a string (uri), into a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python

What is the bestway to convert a string uri like 'abc/efg/hij/klm' and output a nested dictionary like the one below? The input uri could have many slashes.

```
{
    'abc': {
        'dfg': {
            'hij': {
                'klm': {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Recursive function

```py
splitstrg = lambda strlist: {strlist.pop(0): splitstrg(strlist) if strlist else {}}
```

used like so:

```py
strg = 'abc/efg/hij/klm'
splitstrg(strg.split('/'))
```

Output:

```py
{'abc': {'efg': {'hij': {'klm': {}}}}}
```

High performance version:

```py
from collections import deque

splitstrg = lambda strdeq: {strdeq.popleft(): splitstrg(strdeq) if strdeq else {}}
splitstrg(deque(strg.split('/')))
```

Comment: Pass a `deque`, not a `list`, to `splitstrg`, since `popleft` will be far more efficient than `pop(0)`.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I learned something new :)

Answer (score 5):

This code snippet would work - you split the string into a list by the slash token, then reverse it so that you build the nested dictionary inside out:

```
uri = 'abc/efg/hij/klm'.split('/')
uri.reverse()
nested = {}
for i in uri:
    nested = {i:nested}
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner using `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

x = 'abc/efg/hij/klm'
d = reduce(lambda d, k: {k: d}, reversed(x.split("/")), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. split the string on "/"
2. for each word in the above array, build the dictionary from the last word(reversed(words))
3. return the dictionary

```py
def convert2(inpstr):
    inpstr = "abc/efg/hij/klm"
    words = inpstr.split("/")
    d={}
    for i in reversed(words):
        d = {i:d}
    return d
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your answer

Comment: 1. split the string on "/"

2. for each word in the above array, build the dictionary from the last word(reversed(words))

3. return the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This one is not elegant. But simple enough.

```
x= "abc/efg/hij/klm"
l_x = x.split("/")

d = {}
for e in reversed(l_x):
    d = {e: d}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
   uri = 'abc/efg/hij/klm'
    dic = {}
    for key in uri.split('/')[::-1]:
        dic = {key: dic}
    print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'abc': {'efg': {'hij': {'klm': {}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to split the string into a list and use simple recursion

```
def fn(i,dict,a):   
    if i == len(a):
        return {}
    temp = {a[i] : fn(i+1,dict,a)}
    return temp

uri = 'abc/efg/hij/klm'
a = uri.split('/')
dict = fn(0,dict,a)
print dict
```